# how to apply matplotlib span selector on all subplots simultaneously

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, widget, python-3.11, matplotlib-widget

i want the spanselector to display on all available subplots on a matplotlib figure when one spanselector is activated on a single subplot. the other subplots spanselectors must have the  with the same coordinates as the user triggered one on a specific subplot.

currently i have implemented multiple spanselector, but i can only display one at a time by activating through mouse on a specific subplot. i researched online but can't find anything relates to this feature. is this possible?

the following picture shows current state:

[image]

the below picture shows desired outcome:

[image]